# smbget: Can't open directory smb://xx/dir: Operation not permitted

Tags: samba

**smbget** failed to download dir recursively with `-R`

It work fine to get a single file w/o `-R`

```
smbget -u xxx -p xxx  smb://host/dir/file
```

But it failed to download dir'

```
smbget -u xxx -p xxx -R smb://host/dir
```

Comment: Seems a known issue of samba, see https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6482

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by appending username and password into URL, like

```
smbget -R smb://username:password@host/dir
```